# Widget Text Needs to be White

Tags: html, widget-text

I need to change the color to white on the title of a widget that I have in my footer. I looked at the source code and note that it says H4 before and after the text. However, when I change the color of H4 in the global typography, it does not change the color of this widget text. I also found the area for the Widget Header and changed it to white but it also is not changing the text to white on the widget. I see the below when I view source code but when I go into CSS, it will not bring it up when I search. Here is what the code currently says:

```
<section id="media_image-3" class="fusion-footer-widget-column widget widget_media_image"><h4 class="widget-title">Members of:</h4>
```

Comment: Your code is cut off, so you'll need to update that in order to get a quality answer.

Comment: Helo Julie BB - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Unfortunately, while this question may occur in the context of a WordPress site, it's not actually a question related to the WordPress software, and as such may be considered [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for our Stack. [webmasters.se] or [so] might be more appropriate. All that said, I think [this guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/) provides a pretty good start on how to locate the CSS rules which are effecting an element.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code it's a difficult problem to solve, but it sounds like something else is overwriting your code.

You may need to be more specific about the H4 you're targeting `footer h4` for instance.

You may also need to add `!important` to your CSS declaration in order to get it to work. See more about `!important` [here](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).